# C# Change string to new value

Tags: c#, string

I've read somewhere that changing strings won't work in C# once set so i was asking myself how i am able to still accomplish the same result.

My situation is as this:

```
string value1 = "value set one";
string value2 = "value set one";
string value3 = "value set one";
```

After a while in my code it checks a database to see if new values are available. If yes it should change those string to the new values it gets from my web request.

So as i find out i can't simply "over write" these strings. Yet i want to be able to change the strings to a new value. Any ideas how this would work?

Thanks!

Comment: that's not what they meant when they told you strings are immutable

Comment: You are misunderstanding what it means that strings can't change. They are immutable, but there's nothing stopping you assigning a new string to a variable.

Comment: This is what i get when i try that "A local or parameter named 'value1' cannot be declared in this scope because that name is used in an enclosing local scope to define a local or parameter"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Separate the string objects in memory from the variables referring to those objects. If you have a variable named `value1`, you can ***definitely*** tell that variable to point to a *different* or **new** string object in memory:

```
string value1 = "foo";
value1 = "bar"; //this is fine
```

What you *cannot* do is change the object in memory. The memory object used by the string `"foo"` is considered *immutable* (it does not mutate).

Using the above code as an example, the first line of the program first creates a reference variable `value1`. It then creates a string object with value `"foo"`, and finally assigns the `value1` variable to refer to the `"foo"` object in memory. The second line of code does not change the `"foo"` object in memory. Instead, it creates a whole new string object with value `"bar"` at a new location in memory, and updates to the `value1` variable to refer to that new object. The original `"foo"` object in memory still exists, and is completely *unchanged*, but now there is nothing referring it to it, and it can be collected the next time the garbage collector runs.

Let's look at some more code:

```
string value2 = "foo";
value2 = value2.Replace("foo", "bar");
value2.ToUpper();
//final result of value2 is "bar", not "BAR"
```

The first line of code here is effectively the same as before: new variable, new memory object, and make the former refer to the latter. The second line is more interesting. Here, the program looks up the reference in the `value2` variable to find the `"foo"` string object in memory, and calls that object's `Replace()` method. This method returns a *new string object* with value `"bar"` in a whole new location in memory. It does **not** modify the existing `"foo"` object in memory. The new object is then assigned to the `value2` variable. But there's one more line of code to check. The program again looks up the `value2` reference, finds the `"bar"` object in memory, and calls that object's `ToUpper()` method. This method also returns a whole new string object, this time with value "`BAR`". However, this time we don't assign that new object to the variable. `value2` remains unchanged; it still refers to the `"bar"` string object, which was also unchanged. Thus, the final result of `value2` is still `"bar"`.

Note that not all types work this way. Most primitives do, but more complex types can and do allow you to change the underlying object.

Comment: Ah sure! English is not my native language so sometimes i misread things and think it means something different. This answer was perfect to understand how it works. My problem has been solved. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable in C#, that means when you 'change' the value of a string you actually create a new string in memory.

```
string value1 = "value set one"; // first block created on the heap
value2 = "some value"; // a new block created on the heap
```

Comment: "The heap" is not relevant to this situation. Both of those strings will be stored in the string intern pool because they are literals.